# Cell is stretched while using multi row

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to put all the methods in first column of each row.
I have tried something like. I want each method `{Forgy,  Macqueen,  Llyod,  Hartigan-wong}` separated by comma to come in down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
                 {Method} & {Dataset} & {No. of Genes}
                  & {Differentially Expressed} & {Non Differentially Expressed} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Forgy,  Macqueen,  Llyod,  Hartigan-wong}
                 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  \\ \cline{2-5}
                 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ \cline{2-5}
                 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the first row refers to the Forgy method, the second row to Macqueen-Lloyd and the third row to Hartigan-Wong, you shouldn't be using `\multirow`

Comment: @egreg all methods refer to all the rows.

Comment: So probably you can just remove that cell, and put the information in the caption... like it is now it is quite misleading (unless, of course, you have more "multirows" with different methods in the finished table).

Comment: @Rmano Exactly the same I'd suggest! The realization by Zarko clearly show that a reader will mistake the three “multirow” lines to refer each to a different row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For above image you need to reformat `mutirow` cell: instead used `c` column type you need to determine it width with explicit lenght. With help of package `makecell` are broken longer column heads into two line. With this the table is fit in document text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\thead[b]{Method} & \thead[b]{Dataset} & \thead[b]{No.\ of\\ Genes}
& \thead[b]{Differentially\\ Expressed} & \thead[b]{Non Differentially\\ Expressed} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{8em}{Forgy,\\  MacQueen,  Lloyd,\\  Hartigan-Wong}
                 & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  \\ \cline{2-5}
                 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ \cline{2-5}
                 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\multirowcell` with alignment `lc`, rather than `\multirow` to avoid determining empirically a correct width, and load `caption` for the vertical spacing between caption and table.

Comment: @egreg, corrected!